# Unable to initialize and use 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I am trying to create and use a 2D vector of a struct. But things are not working. following is the code snippet I am using.

```
struct Node 
{
int a,b; 
Node() : a(-1) , b(-1){};
};      
int m =5; n=4;    
vector<vector<Node>>T;
    T.resize(m, vector<Node>(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
       {
          T[i].resize(n, Node());
       }
```

After running this, the vector sizes are correctly initialized but the capacity is incorrect. Specifically T has size = capacity = 5, but all T[i] have size 4 and capacity 1.
Nonetheless the element values seem to be correctly initialized.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1t4j.png)
Secondly when I try to modify the vector later on I am unable to do so.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
        T[i][j].a= -1;
        T[i][j].b= -1;
      }
```

On running this , the first element (T[0][0]) is correctly updated but subsequent iterations are causing random elements to be updated. 
I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I tried initializing as

```
vector<vector<Node>>T(m, vector<Node>(n));
```

But still face the same issue in modifying values.

Comment: Seem to work fine here, although I condensed init to `vector<vector<Node> >T(m, vector<Node>(n, Node()));`

Comment: I am using VS 2015 for compilation. I tested with gcc and it seems to be working. Is it possible that it is compiler bug ?

Comment: Visual Studio has never been the friend of STL templates :) That's possible, I'll let the VS experts say more (because really it is a huge bug). Maybe you're missing some service pack?

Comment: I am using Update 1 for VS 2015. Will update VS and see if it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and "Visual Studio 2013 Update 5" shows the following:
[Link](http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0904/c6/2102627ba0fceb1000e5186c9ed674c6.png)

Do not worry, you have just a bug in the IDE;)